# Много кнопок

Tags: flash

Нужно сделать много кнопок для выбора уровня как и в большинстве игр скажите как это реализуется я не думаю что делается на каждую кнопку обработчик

Comment: Перечитал 3 раза, но, к сожалению, так и не понял что именно Вас интересует.
Не могли бы Вы как то конктретизировать свой вопрос, желательно на примерах, а также было бы не плохо что бы Вы сказали чего именно вы хотите добиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

обработчик-слушатель нажатия конечно один, а узнать какая кнопка нажата можно следующими способами:

- (правильный) отнаследовать класс кнопки в свой, со свойством содержащим необходимые данные (public var levelData:LevelDataContainer;), в цикле создания кнопок, это свойство заполняется и при нажатии на кнопку обработчик получает все необходимые данные
- заполнить по своей маске свойства name или id ("ButtonLevel_level_1_noncompleted"), при нажатии парсить его и получать данные
- по координатам кнопки, вычислить колонку и строку, получить порядковый номер кнопы
- (экономный, для iOS/Mobile) не создавать кнопки, нарисовать их картинки в спрайт, подсвечивать по наведению нужный Rect, координаты так же из координат щелчка/тача.

Comment: Вот первый метод самый подходящий мне но я не могу узнать как достать из обработчика (public var levelData:LevelDataContainer;)

Answer (score 0):

```
private function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if ( event.target is MyButton)
    {
         var myButton:MyButton = event.target as Mybutton;
         var levelData:LevelData = myButton.levelData;
    }

{
```

Comment: Только что сам нашел и вы тут к тут ответили. Огромное спасибо что не забываете.